# Getting Invalid value for the key "reminderMinutesBeforeStart" in Outlook "Get Events API"

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi

Getting Invalid value for the key "reminderMinutesBeforeStart" in Outlook [Get Events API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#get-an-event). When the reminder is not set for one of the users.

We are getting "1525252321" minutes as value for the "**reminderMinutesBeforeStart**" key. Please help us to resolve this issue.

Outlook get Event API (Sample request)
`https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/<event_id>?$expand=<expand value>`

Response for your reference:

> {"lastModifiedDateTime":"xxxxx","subject":"xxxxxx","webLink":"xxx","isDraft":false,"bodyPreview":"xxxxx","createdDateTime":"xxxxxx","originalEndTimeZone":"Pacific Standard Time","body":{"contentType":"HTML","content":""},"type":"xxxxx","allowNewTimeProposals":true,"seriesMasterId":null,"@odata.id":"xxxx","**reminderMinutesBeforeStart":1525252321**,"isRoomRequested":false,"id":"xxxxxxx","autoRoomBookingOptions":null,"originalStartTimeZone":"Pacific Standard Time","showAs":"Busy","attendees":[],"@odata.etag":"xxxxxx","responseStatus":{"response":"xxxxx","time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},"transactionId":null,"recurrence":null,"calendar@odata.navigationLink":"xxxxx","changeKey":"xxxxx","isOrganizer":true,"onlineMeeting":null,"sensitivity":"xxxx","isOnlineMeeting":false,"importance":"xxxx","iCalUId":"xxxxx","calendarEventClassifications":[],"onlineMeetingProvider":"Unknown","occurrenceId":null,"autoRoomBookingStatus":"xxxx","isAllDay":false,"calendar@odata.associationLink":"xxxxxxxx","end":{"dateTime":"2021-09-03T23:30:00.0000000","timeZone":"UTC"},"categories":[],"hasAttachments":false,"responseRequested":true,"isCancelled":false,"start":{"dateTime":"2021-09-03T23:00:00.0000000","timeZone":"UTC"},"isReminderOn":false,"hideAttendees":false,"organizer":{"emailAddress":{"address":"xxxxxxx","name":"xxxxxx"}},"onlineMeetingUrl":null,"locations":[],"location":{"address":{"type":"xxxxx"},"uniqueIdType":"xxxxx","displayName":"","coordinates":{},"locationType":"xxxxx"}}